# Finding the maximum x, y and z value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, math

I cannot for the life of me figure out this problem (description listed below) code ive tried so far just returns "none"

```
import math



def farthest_planet(planets):
    plane = 0
    for planet in planets:
        tempval = math.sqrt(int(planet['x']) ** 2 + int(planet['y'] ** 2 + int(planet['z']) ** 2))
        plane = tempval
        if tempval > plane:
            return planet
```

For each planet, you have the 3-dimensional coordinates of its location. A distance can be calculated using the 3D version of the Pythagorean Theorem. In words it is the square root of the sum of the squares of all 3 coordinates. I For example, if a planet is at x = 1, y = 2 and z = 3, its distance is the square root of 1 + 4 + 9. ### Function Name farthest_planet *** Parameters planets: A list of planets. Each planet is a dictionary with keys x, y, and 'ż. The values of these keys are positive floating point values. These values represent the planet's coordinates, with the origin being the center of the star they orbit. ### Return Value The planet from planets that is farthest from the center of the star they orbit. ### Examples `farthest_planet([{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2., 'z': 3. }, { 'x': 10., 'y: 20., 'z': 30. }) -> { 'x': 10., 'y': 20., 'z': 30}`.

Comment: Your tempval is the value of your plane. You'll want to keep track of the furthest_planet, as well as the furthest_distance, and then after you finish your for-loop, then you can return your furthest_planet. Just update your furthest_planet when your calculated distance is greater than your furthest_distance (which by default would be 0).

Comment: Note that since python3.8, you can replace `math.sqrt(int(planet['x']) ** 2 + int(planet['y'] ** 2 + int(planet['z']) ** 2))` with `math.hypot([int(planet[axis]) for axis in ['x', 'y', 'z']])`. One upside of this replacement would be to avoid the small but consequential typo you made with the parentheses. Also note that there is no particular reason to convert to `int` here. What if the coordinates had non-integer numbers in them? Converting to `int` would result in an imprecision. So you could just write `math.hypot(planet.values())`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the max function on the list of planets and give it a key function that computes the distance to the star:

```
planets = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2., 'z': 3. }, { 'x': 10., 'y': 20., 'z': 30. }]

max(planets,key=lambda p:sum(c*c for c in map(p.get,'xyz')))

{'x': 10.0, 'y': 20.0, 'z': 30.0}
```

For distance comparisons, you don't need to apply the square root.  The sum of squares will provide the same relative ordering because if a > b, then √a > √b

Answer (score 1):

with `plane = tempval`, you're automatically overwriting the value of `plane` so they will always equal the same value before you get to the comparison portion of your code.

you want to make the comparison first, then reassign if the value of `tempval` is greater than `plane`.

then at the end of all of your comparisons, return `plane` (so take the return statement out of the for loop altogether).

```
for...
...
    if tempval > plane:
        plane = tempval
return plane
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for the code

```
if tempval > plane:
```

because you make plane = tempval
Instead, code as following:

```
if tempval > plane:
    plane = tempval
    rt_planet = planet
return rt_planet
```